# node.js - can't load my files with express3

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express3 and when I'm trying to load my html/javascript/css files it loads the html without the css.

I'm using this code to load the files -

```
express.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index.html");
    res.sendfile("style.css");
    res.sendfile("script.js");
});
```

So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, link the css and javascript to the page via tags in the header of your HTML

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/path/to/style.css' />
<script src='/path/to/javascript.js'></script>
```

Be sure that you're using the static middleware in your app.use() section, this will tell Express where to find your static files.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now, your Express app should serve your static css and js files.

Answer (score 0):

You link to css and javascript from the html page...

Try looking at the static files example app in the express github repo: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/static-files

Basically you make another http request for static files (.js, .css)